# sharing parent variable between forms

Tags: c#, winforms

form A opens form B, and form A.visible = false;

form A has a public int variable and I need controls in form B to be able to access and modify this variable. could this be done as passing the value through the constructor is only one way!

and so if it could be done, if form A is not visible could the value still be accessed?

(form b is not supposed to be dialog!)

many thanks!

edited: I do not quite get the explanations actually. so far it is like that:

in form a:

```
    //in global space
    public int temp = 123;

    //in form_load event
    Form setup = new setup();
    setup.Show();
    this.Visible = false;
```

in form setup:

```
    //in form_load event
    textBox1.text = temp.toString();

    //in button_press event
    form a.temp = "456";
```

I hope I have explained my stance clearly!

Comment: Yes, this is doable.  Either pass the instance of A to B's constructor, or add a method to B to accept an instance of type A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, have member field in form B of type form A:

```
private FormA parent;
```

Second, have such constructor in form B:

```
public FormB(FormA parent)
    : this()
{
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

Now when you create instance of form B, pass reference to the running form A instance:

```
FormB formB = new FormB(this);
formB.Show();
```

And you can access the public property through the `parent` field e.g.

```
//inside Form B code..
public Foo()
{
    parent.PUblicProp = "Hello";
}
```

Comment: this method works! but my form didnt disappear when i set visibility to false after formb.show()..

Comment: my bad, I set visibility in the form_load method, no wonder it doesnt works. I changed it to using a timer and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

this is one way to pass values from one form to another form

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = MyProperty;
    }
}
```

after that in the button click event handler in Form1
add the following code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.MyProperty = "This is from Form1";
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `int` variable is `public` then your controls in `formB` can access and modify it, `formA` visibility won't affect this it will be accessed disregarding the visibility of it:

```
FormA f = new FormA();
int newValue = f.yourintvariable;
```

And there are a lot of alternative ways like using constructor to send the variable in the `FormA` constructor and initialize it from `FormB`,
or you can define it as `static` but in this case will be one variable for all the instances of thid form